# Как запустить Perl-скрипт под Windows без установки дополнительного ПО?

Tags: perl

Существует один проект — [ExifTool](https://ExifTool.org/) — для работы с метаданными различного рода форматов файлов. Сам проект написан полностью на Perl.

Проблема заключается в том, что необходимо сделать возможным запуск ExifTool под Windows, но без установки Strawberry Perl или ActiveState Perl. На официальном сайте есть версия под Windows, но при каждом запуске он распаковывается в папку %temp% и из-за этого параллельный запуск двух или болей копий не возможен. Как можно сделать запуск ExifTool без установки каких либо программ и чтобы размер был минимальным.

меня по сути утаивает вариант, если сделать две папки:

- bin\perl.exe
- bin\perl514.dll
- папка lib, где находится сам ExifTool и все необходимые компоненты.

Я не знаю, а как мне сделать, чтобы у меня в папке lib были только необходимые компоненты, как это сделано в ExifTool версии под Windows.

И еще один вопрос. Как можно из ExifTool вытащить те скрипты, которые отвечают за работу с JPEG?

Comment: Как вариант перехват для приложения API отвечающих за получение каталога временных файлов GetTempPath и ExpandEnvironmentStrings, с последующей подменой выдачи на созданный временный каталог со случайным именем в нужной тебе папке.Запуск приложения - своим загрузчиком, выполняющим перехват и подмену. Вариант реализации - на любителя.

Comment: Можно и без перехвата API, в батнике:
генерировать случайное имя для %TMP% и/или %TEMP%, создавать эти каталоги, далее set TMP=, set TEMP=, запускать exiftools и прибивать их после.

Comment: а ни как нельзя без распаковки сделать?

Answer (score 2):

> меня по сути утаивает вариант, если
>   сделать две папки:

А так и можно :) Только в PATH прописать путь к perl.exe и таскать это всё по разным машинам без установки, будет работать. Только соблюсти все зависимости от того, что распаковывается во временную папку.

**Обновление**

1. Устанавливаем perl.exe и необходимые dll в `d:\perl\bin` (в 5.12 их 6 штук)
2. Копируем `tmp\что-то\cache-exiftool-xxx\inc\lib` в `d:\perl\lib`
3. Запускаем `perl.exe` exiftool (exiftool лежит в tmp\что-то\cache-exiftool-xxx\inc\scripts)

Если ему чего-то не хватает - сам скажет.

**Обновление 2**

Урезанную версию perl мне ставить некуда, но под 5.12 выдранный из распаковки exiftool и перенесённый в другое место прекрасно работает. Даже без "своего" окружения: http://pastebin.com/21ywsgcY

Может криво объяснил. От перла (на примере 5.12) нужны только

1. perl.exe и dll из `perl/bin`
2. В каталоге `perl/lib` оставляются только те файлы, младшие братья которых находятся в `cache-exiftool-xxx\inc\lib`
3. Из `cache-exiftool-xxx\inc\scripts` берётся только `exiftool`, остальное не нужно.

Всё это займёт около 10 mb и может работать без инсталляции, только при прописывании в PATH пути к X:\perl\bin. Perl для кастрации берётся здесь: http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePerl/releases/

Comment: А можно поподробнее, как это сделать?

Comment: Он так не запустится, я пробовал так, проблема в том, что он требует perl 5.8 а у меня его нету.

Comment: мы можем перенести наш разговор на почту lorents17@mail.ru

У меня проблема в том, что мне выдает ошибку при этом
C:\Users\Lorents\Desktop\perl\bin>perl.exe C:\Users\Lorents\Desktop\perl\exiftool
Perl lib version (v5.8.7) doesn't match executable version (v5.12.4) at Config.pm line 46.

у меня ни как не получается сделать, так как вы говорите?

Comment: Откуда в перле 5.12 берётся Config.pm от 5.8? Этот файл находится в архиве exiftools (inc/lib), а из него вообще никакие файлы не нужны, кроме самого exiftool. Всё остальное надо просто удалить.

Comment: 2) в каталоге perl/lib оставляются только те файлы, младшие братья которых находятся в cache-exiftool-xxx\inc\lib

т.е мне вручную надо удалить все эти файлы? а нет способа автоматизировать. Кстати exiftool ес пользует для запаковки Perl Archiving Toolkit, может это поможет мне.